# flexbox space-evenly not spacing evenly

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I have the following snippet and am wondering why the spacing between the first three elements is not the same as the spacing between the the 3rd and 4th

```css
.textFMT2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.links4 {
    width: 100%;
}

.links4 span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #538231;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 10vw;
    padding: 1vw 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.textFMT2 .arrowsForScroll {
    position: relative;
}

.arrowsForScroll {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2vw;
}

.arrowsForScroll {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

a.left, a.right {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 32px;
}

.left, .right {
    display: none;
}

.sections {
    background-color: #b3d7f7;
    /* width: 32vw; */
    color: #538231;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.links4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="textFMT2">
                            <div class="links4">
                                <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/php/homeCtrl.php?place=Get Involved">Sign up for our<br>Quarterly Newsletter</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="links4">
                                <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/php/homeCtrl.php?place=Calendar">Attend an<br>Event</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="links4">
                                <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/php/homeCtrl.php?place=Get Involved">Volunteer with<br>SWAG</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="arrowsForScroll">
                                <a class="left" href="#section2"><!--&uarr;--> &nbsp;</a>    
                                <div class="links4">
                                    <span><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/swag/public/php/homeCtrl.php?place=Donate">Donate to help<br>our work</a></span>
                                </div>
                                <a class="right" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different gap size is created because you are setting the position to `relative` here:

```
.textFMT2 .arrowsForScroll {
    position: relative;
}
```

An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its normal position.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

So you need to explictly set it to `static`

```
.textFMT2 .arrowsForScroll {
    position: static;
}
```

Static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties.

**An element with `position: static;` is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page**

EDIT: The entire issue stems from having a flex item set to `position: absolute` in `.arrowsForScroll` (which is defined twice by the way), I assume you wrote the selector `.textFMT2 .arrowsForScroll` to compensate for that. So the layout *could also* be fixed by simply removing these two selectors entirely:

```
.textFMT2 .arrowsForScroll {
    position: relative;
}

.arrowsForScroll {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2vw;
}
```